# Split the right substring in a list

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to store the line string in a list to process it. With the current state just the first element is being removed. I want to remove the letter substring from the line string before process it. How can I fix that?

I appreciate any help.

**Simple:**

```
stop 04:48 05:18 05:46 06:16 06:46 07:16 07:46 16:46 17:16 17:46 18:16 18:46 19:16
Apple chair car 04:52 05:22 05:50 06:20 06:50 07:20 07:50 16:50 17:20 17:50 18:20 18:50 19:20
```

**Result:**

```
   [04:48, 05:18, 05:46, 06:16, 06:46, 07:16, 07:46, 16:46, 17:16, 17:46, 18:16, 18:46, 19:16]
   [04:52, 05:22, 05:50, 06:20, 06:50, 07:20, 07:50, 16:50, 17:20, 17:50, 18:20, 18:50, 19:20]
```

**Code:**

```
if (line.contains(":")) {
            String delims = " ";
            String[] tokens = line.split(delims);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(
                    Arrays.asList(tokens));
            list.remove(0);
            System.out.println(tokens);

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First replace and then do splitting.

```
string.replaceFirst("(?m)^.*?(?=\\d+:\\d+)", "").split("\\s+");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lU4oT6/9)

- `string.replaceFirst("(?m)^.*?(?=\\d+:\\d+)", "")` will replace the starting alphabets plus spaces with an empty string.
- Now do splitting on spaces against the resultant string will give you the desired output.

Comment: I am  getting this error `The method replaceFirst(String, String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String)`?

Comment: @MrAsker You shouldn't try editing OP post to description of your problem. Instead ask separate question after you search other questions and will not be able to find solution. In case of code added in this edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8353587 problem is that Strings are immutable so `line.replaceFirst` doesn't change string in `list` but returns new one with replaced values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative without regex, end result will be string that you can split by space.

```
public class StringReplace {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String output = replace("Apple chair car 04:52 05:22 05:50 06:20 06:50 07:20 07:50 16:50 17:20 17:50 18:20 18:50 19:20");

    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

    Collections.addAll(tokens, output.split(" "));          
}

private static String replace(String input) {

    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (char character: chars) {

        // test against ASCII range 0 to ':' and 'space'
        if ((int)character > 47 && (int)(character) < 59 || (int)character == 32)  {

            builder.append(character);  
        }
    }

    return builder.toString().trim();

    }
}
```

Result >> 04:52 05:22 05:50 06:20 06:50 07:20 07:50 16:50 17:20 17:50 18:20 18:50 19:20

Comment: I have tried your solution but when the character is `/` I an getting this error `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1` I have tried to change this condition `(int)character > 47 ` to `(int)character > 46 ` but I am still getting the same error?!

Comment: The erorro I am getting when I store the result in the `newLine` Array string and try to do the following ` for(String time: newLine){
int hour = Character.getNumericValue(time.charAt(1)); }`

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, because it is impossible to get this error from the answer as is. Return value will be String without words before digits and trimmed for spaces. Try to print return value and see for yourself.